# Extract text content from nested HTML while excluding some specific tags; Scrapy

Tags: python, css, xpath, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to extract text content from an HTML tag that has nested content. I took this example from another related question that can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073902/extract-all-text-from-arbitrarily-nested-html).

```
>>> from parsel import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(text='''
    <p>
        Senator <a href="/people/senator_whats_their_name">What&#39s-their-name</a> is <em>furious</em> about politics!
    </p>''')
>>>
>>> # Using XPath
... sel.xpath('normalize-space(//p)').extract_first()
"Senator What's-their-name is furious about politics!"
>>>
>>> # Using CSS
... "".join(sel.css("p *::text").extract())
"Senator What's-their-name is furious about politics!"
```

This is pretty close to what I want. However, I would like to exclude some specific tags. E.g. I would like to exclude the `a` tag's content from the resulting string. I.e. I would like to get:

`Senator  is furious about politics!`

How can I achieve the desired result? My preference would be to keep using Scrapy / Parsel for getting the result, but if no solution exists, I can consider using any other third-party libraries. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use regex to remove `<a>` tags from text first then process. This is not the best way but it will work. `re.sub('<a(.*?)</a>','',your_text)`

Comment: Yes. This can work but I have a dynamic use case where I want to exclude multiple elements based on complex selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- here is working solution using `beautifulsoup`.
- you can find similar functions in scrapy or parsel and use similar approach.
- Idea is to set the content of tags you want to ignore to `''`
- Here is a sample example.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsp

soup = bsp(''' <p>
        Senator <a href="/people/senator_whats_their_name">What&#39s-their-name</a> is <em>furious</em> about politics!
        <h1> I want to be ignored</h1>
        <h2> I should not be ignored</h2>.
    </p>''', 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all(['a', 'h1']): # give the list of tags you want to ignore here.
    tag.replace_with('')

print(soup.text)
```

output:

```
  Senator  is furious about politics!

 I should not be ignored.
```

- Above code will remove all `tags` you want to ignore from text.
- Following function will just change `string(text)` and keep tags as it is.

```
for tag in soup.find_all(['a', 'h1']):
    tag.string.replace_with('')
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
 <p>
        Senator <a href="/people/senator_whats_their_name"></a> is <em>furious</em> about politics!
        <h1></h1>
<h2> I should not be ignored</h2>.
    </p>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! Although I can't find anything equivalent for Scrapy but I'll use bs4 for this for now.